# How to use VBA to search in Internet Explorer?

Tags: vba, internet-explorer

I am new here/to programming. I am trying to use VBA to input some text into a webpage through internet explorer.

I am able to open explorer through VBA and navigate to the page, but I am unable to enter text in the searchbar. When I click "inspect element" on the search bar, it returns this:

```html
    <input class="ui-autocomplete-input" id="la-input" 
          maxlength="2147483647" 
          placeholder="Search by Name, Last Name, First Name, or Account Name" 
          autocomplete="off">
```

This is the code I am trying to modify to get to run:

```vb
    'get a reference to the search form, by finding its id in the
    
    'web page's document object model
    
    Dim ieElement As Object
    
    Set ieElement = ieApp.document.getElementByID("search")
    
    'search box is composed of text box (item 0) and button (item 1)
    'set value of text box to what we're searching for
    ieElement(0).Value = "Excel VBA courses"
    
    'click the button!
    ieElement(1).Click
```

Thank you!!

Comment: `Set ieElement = ieApp.document.getElementByID("la-input"): ieElement.Value = "Excel VBA courses"` but it's unclear where the button is in this case.  That (0) and (1) is not how it works in this case.

Comment: try Tim's suggestion. If doesn't work please share the url if possible and explain what didn't work with Tim's suggestion.

Comment: Thanks @TimWilliams. Is there anyway to try and figure out where the button is?

Comment: In the browser right-click the button and choose 'Inspect" - that should give you the HTML for the button.